# Cypress/Javascript - how to wait for a element to not have a class?

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am having a little issue with my javacript/cypress code.

What I am trying to do is that if the user clicks on a button (it's an `<a>` link in the html further below) then wait until the class selectionAdded is removed from the dom with that `<a>` link.

Let me show you what I mean. Here is the button:

```
<a class="oddsBoostedPrice   button__bet eventSelection--link" "="">
```

Click on the button and a class appears briefly known as .selectionAdded (represents the front end as the 'Added' text hovering over the button).

```
<a class="oddsBoostedPrice   button__bet eventSelection--link selectionAdded" "="">
```

After a few moments, the 'Added' hover disappears from the button and so the element now looks like this (`.selected` class is added but more importantly it's back to a clickable state which only happens once `.selectionAdded` is removed from the dom).

```
<a class="oddsBoostedPrice   button__bet eventSelection--link selected" "="">
```

So basically my logic below is basically stating find an element that's not already selected, click on it, break from loop and then wait for element to not contain class selectionAdded (to ensure button is clickable state as later on I will click the same button).

```
const oddsSelectionElements = new OddsSelectionElements();

When ("User selects an available bet bundle selection", () => {
  oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton().each((element, index) => {
      if (element.not("have.class", "selected")) {
      oddsSelectionElements.selectionName().eq(index).invoke("text").then(formatters.formatString).as("selectionName");
      cy.wrap(element).click();
      return false;
    }
  })
   oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton().not("have.class", "selectionAdded"); 
})
```

class OddsSelectionElements

```
class OddsSelectionElements {

    oddsButton() {
        return cy.get('.button__bet')
    }
 
}
```

export default OddsSelectionElements

My issue is that my test is flakey and it looks like it's because sometimes later on the test, it clicks the button when it's not in a clickable state and I believe it's because it's not waiting until the button does not have that `selectionAdded` class.

What needs to happen to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to fix this you can add timeouts. This can be local to a single command or global as well. By default, cypress has a timeout of 4 seconds

To apply timeout locally, you can do something like this:

```js
//timeout for 7 seconds
cy.get('selector', { timeout: 7000 }).("have.class", "selectionAdded")
```

Or, if you want to increase the timeout globally for all commands, Go to `cypress.json` and add:

```js
defaultCommandTimeout: 7000
```

Also please change:

```js
oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton().("not.have.class", "selectionAdded")
```

Comment: Hmmm,, this doesn't seem to have an affect. I wrote it this way:  `oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton({ timeout: 7000}).not("have.class", "selectionAdded");`

Comment: You have to add it here `return cy.get('.button__bet', { timeout: 7000})`

Comment: Is that good coding practice though? Because wouldn't that mean we always have to wait 7 seconds for that element maximum? Shouldn't it timeout if selectionAdded is still in that element rather than timeout on the button itself?

Comment: Yes, it is. using `cy.wait(7000)` is a bad practice because no matter what cypress will wait for 7 seconds. with a timeout, if the condition is met before 7 seconds then cypress moves onto next commands. So in your case, the maximum time of waiting is now 7 seconds.

Comment: Ok cool, fair enough. So different to Java and gauge which I'm more use to :) I tried your solution but again not working. I don't know if I put `oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton().not("have.class", "selectionAdded");` in the right place in the code above?

Comment: You can increase the timeout then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236994/discussion-between-bruceybandit-and-alapan-das).

Answer (score 3):

Cypress [.not() command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/not#Syntax) should be passed a selector

```js
cy.get('selector').not('.selected')
```

The way you use it is not valid syntax, but does not give an error unfortunately

```js
.not("have.class", "selectionAdded")  // "have.class" can't be used with .not()
```

---

In your test

```js
oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton()
  .each((element, index) => {
    if (element.not(".selected").length === 0) {     
      oddsSelectionElements.selectionName()
        .eq(index)
        .invoke("text")
        .then(formatters.formatString).as("selectionName");
      cy.wrap(element).click();
      return false;
    }
  })
oddsSelectionElements.oddsButton().not(".selectionAdded");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try checking the element's css like this

```js
if (!element.css("selected")) {
  ...
```